# What is the correct IATA airplane designator for the Boeing 787-10?

Tags: boeing-787, iata

[Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ICAO_aircraft_type_designators) `781`, [most other sources say](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k11416309-o10-What_is_the_Airbus_A350_900_359-Air_Travel.html) `78J`.  I can't find anything authoritative, and IATA has the gall to [want US$578 for the answer](https://www.iata.org/publications/store/Documents/Passenger%20Standards/specifications-aircraft-types-app-a.pdf).  Which one is it?

*Update for clarity*: Everybody agrees that the four-letter ICAO code is `B78X`. I'm interested in the three-letter IATA code.

Comment: IATA isn't ICAO. The title and question body says IATA, but the WIkipedia link says ICAO, and it would seem that ICAO is what you're going for. Please [Edit] appropriately.

Comment: @aCVn The Wikipedia page actually lists both ICAO and IATA (2nd column) codes. It does indeed say **B78X** (ICAO) and **781** (IATA) for the Boeing 787-10. The references on the Wikipedia page only list ICAO codes though...

Comment: IATA must make literally thousands of dollars annually from this charge.

Comment: Until yesterday we had an answer from someone who actually _asked_ IATA and posted their reply. What happened to that answer?

Comment: @PerlDuck I've just accepted that answer.  There was a third answer offering dubious sources, but that was heavily downvoted and seems to have been deleted now.

Comment: @jpatokal I meant another one. It was posted yesterday by someone with (I guess) ~7000 rep and is now deleted. Last time I looked it had +3. Never mind. Maybe I ask someone in the chat.

Comment: I still do not consider this question satisfactorily answered, and I think @jpatokal you may very well have awarded the bounty in vain. I'm not calling anybody a liar, but there's just no way to verify the contents of IATA SSIM Annex A (the correct product number of the current SSIM Appendix A would be 8803-28). The deleted answer referred to above was downright weird, as it claimed to show a direct quote from an email, but the embedded link in it clearly was not from an email created by IATA SSIM Team, as it referred to ESA site. That just does not happen with copy/paste

Comment: @Jpe61: One cannot copy and paste a hyperlink into an answer straight away, it has to be done manually (try it), so it was a honest mistake. I'd be more suspicious like you if it was a new user, but rep points matter, and they're a [measure of trust](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). PS To whomever downvoted it, if you're new, it wasn't a good [reason](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) to downvote. PPS The author deleted it for another reason(s).

Comment: @ymb1 ok, that would explain it, but I still think it's odd. Not saying I would not be able to make a mistake like that myself...  I do understand very well that rep can measure trust, especially when it's in thousands, hard to get there dishonestly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked it up in the corresponding IATA document and I can confirm it is **781**.

Sadly I think I am not allowed to attach any kind of proof from the document but the source of my information is IATA document *8803 - Aicraft Types* in version no. 28.

Answer (score 2):

United flies the 787-10 between Newark (EWR) and Frankfurt (FRA) on the 787-10. Knowing this, I did a [search on ITA](https://matrix.itasoftware.com/#search:research=EWRFRA) with an extension code to filter for specific aircraft types in the results. With either `AIRCRAFT t:787` or `t:781`, the expected flight was returned. Using `t:78J` with the rest of the search unchanged yielded no results, so it appears that `781` is at least valid, and possibly the definitive answer since it seems unlikely that multiple codes would be in use.

Comment: *Note:* Wikipedia has now changed to **78J**. The [change](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_aircraft_type_designators&diff=prev&oldid=899788630) was done on 1 June with the reason: "Wikipedia is the only source on the internet that claims `781`".

Comment: This answer unfortunately does not provide certainty into this matter. Yes, 781 would _appear_ to be a _valid code_ for 787-10, but there is no proof it is the official IATA designator.